# Cardinality of Sets Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $k \in N$, let 
$S_k = \{A \subseteq N : |A| =k\}$. Show that $|S_2| = | N |$

[Hint: Define $f: S_2 \rightarrow N$ by $f(\{a,b\}) = 2^u3^v$ with 
$u = \min\{a,b\}, v = \max\{a,b\}$. Then argue that $|S_2| = |f(S_2)|$
and $f(S_2)$ is denumerable
as in the last question.]

My question is how do the min/max add to the solution?  They seem unnecessary to me, which makes me feel like maybe I am missing something important.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it's to avoid confusion: for instance $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$ so if you defined it as $2^a3^b$ it could be quite unclear as to what $a,b$ are  (is $a=1$ or $a=2$?) as they are completely arbitrary.

Comment: A possibly nicer way to avoid the problem would be instead to define $f(\{a,b\})$ as $2^a+2^b$.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about the natural numbers in the natural ordering. But sets have no internal structure, there's no importance which element is the first and which is the second.

In order to identify which of the two elements goes to the power of $2$, and which one goes to the power of $3$ you need to choose. And there is a very obvious way of making this choice: the smaller one goes to the power of the smaller number.